# Keep example boxes of text in the same spot on top of image

Tags: css

I have a simple image with boxes. For the uploaded sample, I am using the dummy image as a placeholder. What I am trying to do is keep the text (Example, Example2, Example 3) in same spot even if the page resize, but it doesn't work. How can this be solved.

```css
    .center {
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 50%;
        }

        #example {
            color:white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            left: 680px;
            width:300px;
            height: 50px;
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: transparent;
            
        }
        #example2 {
            color:white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 120px;
            left: 930px;
            width:300px;
            height: 50px;
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: transparent;
            
        }
        
        #example3 {
            color:white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 200px;
            left: 730px;
            width:300px;
            height: 50px;
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: transparent;
            
        }

        #container {
            position: relative;
        }
```

```html
   
    <div id="container">
        <div id="example">I am Training | Apr 16 – Jun 15<br> 60 days</div>
        <div id="example2">Compliance |<br> Jun 11 – Jul 11</div>
        <div id="example3">Harassment Free<br> Work May 11</div>
        <img class="center" src="https://dummyimage.com/758x428/000/fff" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing by "in the same spot" you mean "in the same spot relative to the image". I don't know if you're speaking about both width and height, but I imagine width. To achieve this, instead of giving the "left" value of the absolutely positioned texts, you can use a percentage, as I have in the snippet:

(If you do want the text to move vertically, you can also assign a percentage there)

```css
.center {
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 50%;
        }

        #example {
            color:white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 40px;
            left: 50%;
            width:300px;
            height: 50px;
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: transparent;
            
        }
        #example2 {
            color:white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 120px;
            left: 60%;
            width:300px;
            height: 50px;
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: transparent;
            
        }
        
        #example3 {
            color:white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 200px;
            left: 50%;
            width:300px;
            height: 50px;
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: transparent;
            
        }

        #container {
            position: relative;
        }
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <div id="example">I am | Apr 16 – Jun 15<br> 60 days</div>
        <div id="example2">Medicaid Compliance |<br> Jun 11 – Jul 11</div>
        <div id="example3">Harassment Free<br> Work May 11</div>
        <img class="center" src="https://dummyimage.com/758x428/000/fff" />
    </div>
```